# Automaton for 'almost' same word in language

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have some finite language L, which is regular.

I want to find a finite automaton (DFA/NFA) that for every word w in L, it accepts any word with the same length but only with 1 char diffrence.

I thought about maybe accept DFA for L, because it a regular language and think about an NFA solution, but my problem is those possible "circles" in the automata..

Any idea?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? "think about an NFA solution" doesn't really help us understand what your difficulty was, which makes it rather hard to address any answer.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine.  The only edits to the question changed the tags, and changed "anyword" to "any word" and "automata" to "automaton", so any lack of clarity is yours and yours alone. Can we expect an apology?

Comment: Comment wasnt aimed to you if you werent the one who downvoted the question, nevertheless iapologize if you think that i was talking to you directly, i ment to whoever felt the undefined need to downvote an answered question. Ran fully answered my question, instead of downvotes i expect people to ask me more soi can be more informative about what i need. This is not a stupid pointless question that deserves it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main Idea:
Construct two copies of the DFA for $L$. The first copy will be connected to the second copy by moves that will allow the "difference" of a single letter. For example, if $q_1$ and $q_2$ are connected by a $0$-move in the original DFA, then $q_1$ in the first copy will be connected to $q_2$ in the second copy by a $1$-move.

Comment: tbh, i solved it like 3 minutes before u wrote it..feeling so smart right now

Comment: moral: never give up so easily – you can do it!

Comment: having some issue defining the FUNCTION formally.. I have Q1 and Q2 as configutations. i want to define the function f1 that it has 2 result. f1(q1,a) if q1 belongs to Q1 or moving to M2 which is the second automata.. do you know what i need to add to the definition?

Comment: @OriRefael not sure I get your second question.